# Get All Documents with access to it's Children in Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the documents of each child collection (ratings) and set the average rating to the  foobar document, but I keep receiving this error in one of my callable functions:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at isLength (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11713:22)
    at isArrayLike (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11333:31)
    at keys (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13307:14)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4900:21
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:183:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
```

Code:

```
const fooBarQuerySnapshot = await db
    .collection("foobars")
    .orderBy('ratingCount', 'desc')
    .get();

const fooBars = fooBarQuerySnapshot.docs
    .map(async (x: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        // get foo bar data
        const data = x.data();
        
        // get sub collection of ratings
        const ratingQuerySnapshot = await db
            .collection(collectionName)
            .doc(x.id)
            .collection('ratings')
            .get();
            
        // set avg rating from the subcollection of ratings
        data.avgRating = ratingQuerySnapshot.docs
             .map((y: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => y.data().rating)
             .reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0) / data.ratingCount;
        return data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` that you get means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.

This makes sense if consider that:

- The Firestore API returns a `DocumentSnapshot` object, which is a complex object that contains circular references to other objects, so it tend get big.
- You are getting every `ratingCount` document and afterwards getting every `ratings` document for each `ratingCount`.

In order to fix it, you could limit the amount of documents that you get on your `ratings` collection, you can find more details on how to implement `limit` in firestore queries in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#top_of_page), process what need to process and then take the next batch of documents to operate.